# Creating ECC Signature - Is "R" necessary in calculating "S"

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

After going through the mathematical proof in confirming ECDSA, it doesn't seem apparent to me that "R" is necessary in calculating "S" for the signature.

**In other words, what's the problem with using the following equation to calculate "S", $S = \frac{z + dA}{k}$**

Let me explain in more detail... a few of the proofs I've found online use the following logic:

In **creating** the signature, the following equation is used to calculate S.

1) $S = \frac{z + dA(R)}{k}$ where k is random number, z is hash digest, dA is private key, R is x1 of P(x1,y1) = k (G), & G is base point.

In **confirming** the signature the following equation is used:

2) $P(x_1,y_1) = \frac{(z)(G) + R(Qa)}{S}$ where Qa is public key and R is x1 of P(x1,y1)

The proof that I found states the following. Since we are interested in using eq #2 to calculate D which equals (k)(G) where D is x1 and Qa = (dA)(G) then we can re-write equation #2 as the following:

$(k)(G) = \frac{(z)(G) + (R)(dA)(G)}{S}$ which can be reduced to the following:

$(S)(G) = \frac{(z + (R)(dA))*G}{k}$which is the same as

$S = \frac{z + (R)(dA)}{k}$ which is the same equation as equation #1.

**In calculating S to create the signature, couldn't we also just use the following equation:
$S = \frac{z + dA}{k}$ where the "R" is omitted? If you re-do the above proof it works without multiplying dA by "R" assuming you also omit "R" form Equation #2 to confirm the signature. 
The benefit or necessity of multiplying dA by "R" to calculate "S" is not apparent to me.**

Thank you!

Comment: Kudos for the improved form! If time/motivation allows, you might want to improve to the point where your equation 1 becomes$$S = k^{-1}(z + d_A\,R)\bmod n\tag{1}$$ where $n$ is the order of $G$ (use right-click then _show math as TeX commands_ to see the internals). It is not standard to use $\frac x k$ to denote multiplication of $x$ by the modular inverse of $k$ (as is the case here). Perhaps: use e.g. $\times$ to denote Elliptic Point multiplication, that helps to distinguish that from modular multiplication; and use $Q_A$ rather than $Q_a$ if you keep $d_A$.

Comment: I need to start using latex more frequently....I like it.

Comment: My math skills are a bit rusty from my engineering days... you'll have to excuse me.

Comment: Regarding my "proposed" signature system: $$S=k^{-1}(z+dA)  mod n$$ where $n$ is the order of $G$...  Assuming $k$ is random shouldn't $S$ be "unique" every-time $S$ is calculated thereby preventing an adversarial from determining the private key, $d_A$?

Comment: Yes, $S=k^{-1}(z+d_A)\bmod n$ would be random and unique for every signature, since $k$ is random in $[1,n)$,and it is unlikely that $z+d_A\equiv 0\pmod n$. Problem is, the verification procedure would need to be changed, and (depending on how) it would either become possible to find $d_A$, or possible to sign without knowing $d_A$. Detail what would be the signature an how it would be verified, and that will become evident.

Comment: i'm thinking....

Comment: I think I got it....

Comment: if the signature was verified with the equation $$R = S^{-1}(z\times G+Q_A)$$ the adversary could  easily determine whatever $R$ and $S$ is necessary to satisfy this equation if they knew the public key $Q_A$ and the hash digest $z$.

Comment: Having $R \times Q_A$ in the standard equation:  $R=S^{-1}(z \times G + R \times Q_A)$ is a one-way function in the numerator making it difficult for them to determine the $R$ value needed to solve the equation unless they knew the private key and could also calculate $S$.